# Is it true that pixelization can be reversed given enough frames?

Tags: editing, effects, filter, production

I just read someone stating the following on a [Kdenlive bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=390595#c6):

> I'd much rather have a single color than pixelization, since with
> enough frames, pixelization can be reversed.

Simple question - is it true? Has it been demonstrated in practice?

Comment: A bit hard to answer without some more context.